# How to clear browser's memory/cache of page scroll position?

Tags: html, css

UPDATE: It turns out the problem was with the browser caching or somehow memorizing the vertical scroll position of the window from a time when I made the browser window very small, forcing the client area to be moved upwards beyond the top of the client rect, resulting in negative *top* position property values.  I discovered this when I closed the page completely and reopened it in a new tab by pasting in the URL.  Note, simply refreshing the page even with *SHIFT+R* does *not* clear the condition.

*So how can I clear/reset the browser's "memory" of the page's scroll position myself so I watch for this occurrence and reset the scroll position cleanly when it happens?*

---

I am having a continual struggle getting my page elements to align properly.  My current issue is that the HTML and BODY tag elements always end up with a negative *top* property value, as reported by *getBoundingClientRect()*.  This results in child elements being shifted around in an unwanted manner vertically, and throwing off certain other coordinate and sizing calculations.

NOTE-1: the reason I ended up using *100vh* for the *height* property is because I tried a **huge** number of *height, min-height* combinations that also involved using *percent* and *pixel* values.  Nothing worked, and I always ended up with 0 height values for *offsetHeight* property.  Because I dynamically size various elements I need to know what the actual value of that property is, so the zero height values were a page breaker.  Using the viewport value format as in *100vh* was the **only** thing I tried that got me non-zero values for the *offsetHeight* property.

NOTE-2: As you can see, I have a DIV element with absolutely positioning that ends up holding a ThreeJS canvas area.  However, I set a breakpoint *before* the ThreeJS canvas is attached to the page and before the ThreeJS elements are initialized, and when I inspect the *top* value for the HTML and BODY elements, those values are already *negative*.  So I don't think the problem is related to using ThreeJS.

Given the HTML and CSS below, why am I getting negative values for the HTML and BODY tag elements and how can I fix it?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: slategrey;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

table#outer-table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

tr#tr-header {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 100px;
}

tr#tr-game-area {}

tr#tr-button-row {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}

div#div-threejs-canvas-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* Set the Z-order to something higher than normal so it's shown on top of the underlay table. */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">

  <body>
    <script src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
    <table id="outer-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="tr-header">
          <td id="td-header">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr-game-area">
          <td id="td-table-cat-cards">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr-button-row">
          <td id="td-button-row">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="div-threejs-canvas-area"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to _do_? You probably shouldn't be using <table>s for layout, but e.g. CSS flexbox or CSS grid.

Comment: add your JS so we can see the result

Comment: @TemaniAfif The JS has a ton of ThreeJS stuff in it.  I set a breakpoint at the very top of the document ready handler, before any of the JS runs at all, and the negative "top" values were already visible.  That is, the breakpoint is before any of the other JS code is called.  Thanks for the edits of my post.  I picked up a few valuable techniques from them.

Comment: try to add the smallest JS possible that shows the negative value. Maybe by reducing the code you will find the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Turns out it's some weird issue with the browser memorizing the vertical scroll position of the page.  See my new update to my original post.

Comment: I see this a lot in single page apps. Scroll down, click something that triggers a "route" which just change content, and i'm still scrolled down. The only solution I've found is to use an old fashion auto-scroll-to-top when the navigation (or other action) is detected